# Could not find method compile() for arguments [com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-telemetry:6.1.0]

Tags: nativescript, mapbox, nativescript-vue, mapbox-android

I'm trying to implement mapbox in my nativiscript app using [@nativescript-community/ui-mapbox](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nativescript-community/ui-mapbox) plugin. With regard to the [documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nativescript-community/ui-mapbox), it should be added :

`<service android:name="com.mapbox.services.android.telemetry.service.TelemetryService" />`
to the `<application>` node of `app/App_Resources/Android/AndroidManifest.xml`.

But when running the `tns run android` command, I get the following error:

```js
Could not find method compile() for arguments
[com.mapbox.mapboxsdk:mapbox-android-telemetry:6.1.0] 
on object of type org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.dsl.dependencies.DefaultDependencyHandler.
```